# Save reordered RecyclerView in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

So I'm trying to implement `Drag-and-Drop` within my To Do List app, but I am having trouble saving the order of the rows once moved - i.e. I moved the items, exited the app and it reverted back to its original position. I thought of a solution.

**My Solution:**

Create a column in my table: specified_position. Every time a row is moved, the `onItemMove()` method returns a `fromPosition` and `toPosition`. Move the row's position to `toPosition`, then increment/update all values there and above. Every time the table is read, it checks the positions and orders them according to it.

**My Question:**

Is my solution correct? Is there a better, easier even method instead to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you made it working? Help me on the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665019/android-recycleview-item-on-drop-is-not-getting-sorted-properly-with-sqlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem on my To Do List app. Here I share my solution with you.

First I have an `updateSortID()` function on my **Database Helper**

```
public void updateSortID(Integer newID,int rowid)
{
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String strSQL = "UPDATE " +  TABLE_NAME_todos +  " SET " + ITEM_SORT_ID +  "=" + newID + " WHERE " + ID +" = "+ rowid;

        db.execSQL(strSQL);
}
```

Then on activity or adapter, where you should listen your position change of items, you need to have an function like this. It will update all sort ID's of all items that affected from this position changes.

```
@Override
public void drop(int from, int to) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d("drop", String.valueOf(from));
    Log.d("drop", String.valueOf(to));

    ArrayList<Items> temp = db.getToDos();

    int tempstart = from;
    int tempend = to;

    if (from < to) {
        Log.d("up to down", "yes");
        db.updateSortID(temp.get(tempend).getSortID(), temp.get(tempstart).getID());
        for (int i = from; i <= to - 1; i++) {
            db.updateSortID(temp.get(i).getSortID(), temp.get(i+1).getID());
        }
    } else if (from > to) {
        Log.d("up to down", "no");
        db.updateSortID(temp.get(tempend).getSortID(), temp.get(tempstart).getID());            
        for (int i = from; i >= to + 1; i--) {
            db.updateSortID(temp.get(i).getSortID(), temp.get(i-1).getID());                
        }
    }

    listChanged(); // this is the method I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method and other related functions
}
```

Comment: Your solution can be applicable but you have to keep sortId's latest position since it can be changeable via Drag & Swipe

Comment: @EminAyar What is the `ITEM_SORT_ID` and can I use this for `RecyclerView` with `ItemTouchHelper` with method `onMove` ?

Comment: @Ucdemir i applied this but sometimes it does not work , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665019/android-recycleview-item-on-drop-is-not-getting-sorted-properly-with-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

As alternative way of answer @Emin Ayar

**clearView** method of **ItemTouchHelper.Callback** Class is called only once not exactly same with **onMove** and **onSwiped** methods...

*onMove* and *onSwiped* are called multiple times...Because of it move or swipe every elements that is affected...

But **clearView** methods is called only one times...

so in this method, delete every elements on Sqlite and add new list, can be another solution...

```
 @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

        db.deleteAllFavoriteNewspapers();

        for(NewspaperClass nc : mAdapter.list){
            db.insertToFavoriteNewspapers(nc);
        }
    }
```

[Tutorial for Drag & Swipe](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.o5n6gju22)