# android - recycleView item on drop is not getting sorted properly with sqlite

Tags: android

I have implemented a recycle view On drag & drop the sorting item in the recycle view. But sorting is not accurate, sorting not working properly. I tried write below code

```
@Overid
 private void onDrop(int from, int to) {   // this listener only calls when item Droped after drag
            List<ExerciseDetails>  temp = items;
            int tempstart = from;
            int tempend = to;

            if (from < to) {
              //  Log.d("  down to up", "yes");

                for (int i = from; i <= to - 1; i++) {
                    exercisesDAO.updateSortID(temp.get(i).getOrder(), temp.get(i+1).getExDetailsId());
                } 
                exercisesDAO.updateOrder(items.get(from).order,items.get(to).exDetailsId);
            } else { //if(from > to)
               // Log.d("up to down", "no"); 
                for (int i = from; i >= to + 1; i--) {
                    exercisesDAO.updateSortID(temp.get(i).getOrder(), temp.get(i-1).getExDetailsId());
                } 
                exercisesDAO.updateOrder(items.get(to).order,items.get(from).exDetailsId);
            } 
            Log.e("sdds","***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ***** ");
        }


public void updateSortID(String newID,Long rowid) {
        String strSQL = "UPDATE " +  DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS +  " SET " + DBHelper.COLUMN_ORDER_ID +  "=" + newID + " WHERE " + DBHelper.COLUMN_EX_DETAILS_ID  +" = "+ rowid;
        mDatabase.execSQL(strSQL);
    }
```

DAO

```
  /*
     * Check whether the exercise data present or not in the db before executing statement
     */
    public  void updateOrder(String orderNewValue, Long rowId) {
    
        String Query = "Update " + DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS + " SET " + DBHelper.COLUMN_ORDER_ID + " = " + orderNewValue +  " Where " + DBHelper.COLUMN_EX_DETAILS_ID + " = " + rowId;
    
        mDatabase.execSQL(Query);
    }
```

Comment: why you are calling `updateSortID` with temp list and call `updateOrder` with items to update the DB?

Comment: What is `COLUMN_EX_DETAILS_ID` exactly? `_id` or `exercise_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the `order` value of `ExerciseDetails` has never been updated in addition to some confusion in changing orders. However, I have changed your code a bit to fix these issues.

As both `updateOrder` and `updateSortID` exactly execute the same query, so I use only `updateOrder` and it seems that `orderNewValue` should be long (not String).

```
public void updateOrder(Long orderNewValue, Long rowId) {
    String query = "Update " + DBHelper.TABLE_EXERCISE_DETAILS + " Set " + DBHelper.COLUMN_ORDER_ID + " = " + orderNewValue +  " Where " + DBHelper.COLUMN_EX_DETAILS_ID + " = " + rowId;
    mDatabase.execSQL(query);
}
```

and `onDrop` becomes like following:

```
@Override
void onDrop(int from, int to) {
    // retain order of `to` item before changing orders:
    long orderTo = items.get(to).getOrder();

    // swap order values for `to` item and other middle items (except `from` item):
    if (from < to) {
        for (int i = to; i > from; i--) {
            ExerciseDetails item = items.get(i);
            long newOrder = items.get(i - 1).getOrder();
            item.setOrder(newOrder);
            exercisesDAO.updateOrder(newOrder, item.getExDetailsId());
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = to; i < from; i++) {
            ExerciseDetails item = items.get(i);
            long newOrder = items.get(i + 1).getOrder();
            item.setOrder(newOrder);
            exercisesDAO.updateOrder(newOrder, item.getExDetailsId());
        }
    }

    // set order for `from` item after swaping orders:
    ExerciseDetails itemFrom = items.get(from);
    itemFrom.setOrder(orderTo);
    exercisesDAO.updateOrder(orderTo, itemFrom.getExDetailsId());
}
```

After all, note that you should never do an I/O job in the main thread. So, consider to run `updateOrder` in another thread somehow based on your app structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Overid
private void onDrop(int from, int to) {   // this listener only calls when item Droped after drag
    ExerciseDetails moveItem = items.remove(from);
    items.add(moveItem, to)
    int minPosition = from > to ? to : from;
    int maxPosition = from > to ? from : to;
    // now the item index is the sort index of ExerciseDetails
    for (int i = minPosition; i <= maxPosition; i++) {
        ExerciseDetails item = items.get(i);
        item.setOrder(i);
        exercisesDAO.updateOrder(i, item.getExDetailsId());
    }
    // notify recyclerview to refresh the position of item dragged
    adapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to)
}
```

Comment: in second line `items.add(moveITem, to)` compile time error.  `in add(int, ExerciseDetails) can be applied to (ExerciseDetails, int)

Comment: @Dan Oh yes, I wrote the reverse, the correct code should be `items.add(to, moveItem);`. So dose my answer solve your problem?